# How to get line count on all files create last month?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, command-line, grep

I am trying to get the line count for all *.rules file created last month. July.
I have tried `ls -ll *.rules |grep "Jul"|while read line; do wc -l $line; done`
Doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you mean in a given folder or system wide, and are they in nested folders? if you have a list of files already, you can let wc do all the work, i.e. `wc -l $(fileList generating commands)`

Comment: I'm looking in a given folder for files created in July only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use find instead :

```
find . -name "*.rules" -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt "01-Jul-2017" -and -not -newermt "01-Jul-2017 +1 month"
```

You can remove the "-maxdepth 1" if you want the search to be recursive.

Regards!

Comment: op wanted line count and only *.rules files, so add `-name "*.rules"` to the end of the find statement and put the whole thing inside `wc -l $(<find goes here>)`

Comment: Edited. I did not even mention "wc". I assumed OP is a smart guy and he needed help to get the list of files ( as his attempt proves so, regardless of it not working entirely), not to count a bunch of lines. Why the down vote though?

Comment: @Austin_Anderson - it's better to use `find | xargs wc -l`. Especially if the filenames could contain whitespaces.

Comment: Thanks so much guys,
I went with this: `find . -name "*.rules" -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt "01-Jul-2017" -and -not -newermt "01-Jul-2017 +1 month" | xargs wc -l`